# Send my ribbon with word document to another user

Tags: outlook, ms-word, word-addins

I have added a Customized ribbon to my word document that has a button run a Macro. When I open the document locally, the extra tab on the ribbon shows(Because I created it). When I send it to a colleague as a attachment through Outlook, they tell me they cant see the customized ribbon.

I know the Macro is there but is there but is there a way to send the format of my customized ribbon WITH the word document so they don't have to set it up and it just shows on their end to? 
[image]

Comment: What method did you use to add the customisation?

Comment: RIght clicked the ribbon area < From the Customize Ribbon section I added a new group names 'Macros'  < A New Tab names 'Update All Fields' and added the specific macro I want to use from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ribbon mods made with the Word program interface are installation-specific and do not travel with the document. Document-specific ribbon mods are usually created with a an editor utility like this one: [Office RibbonX Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor/releases/tag/v1.5.1)

There are many web pages about modifying the ribbon, here is an introductory article: [Modifying the User Interface in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/word/ribbonmodification.htm) Here's one that is more in-depth: [Customize the Word Ribbon User Interface](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html)

As an alternative, you can add macros to the Quick Access Toolbar with the Word interface. To ensure they travel with the document, open **File>Options>Quick Access Toolbar** and set the *Customize Quick Access Toolbar* dropdown to **For MyDocument.docm**, where MyDocument is the name of your file. The QAT icons will be added to the right end of the QAT and have the side benefit of automatic keyboard shortcuts. As an example, you can run the 5th QAT icon by pressing Alt + 5 on your keyboard.

Comment: Update: The quick access toolbar option was perfect for this scenario. Thanks!